# Angular App Shell Build Created 2 folder in dist folder what is this and how to use

Tags: angular, angular6

my problem is that when I run `ng run my-app:app-shell -c` production command. this command created 2 folders in dist folder one is a browser and  one is server folder

my question is that now I have 2 commands

`npm build --prod` (for the normal build) only browser folder is created

`ng run my-app:app-shell -c production` (for check the app shell is working or not)  browser folder a server folder is created

what is the server folder and how to use it?

help me

Answer (score 0):

For building the app-shell, Angular uses Angular Universal, a technology that renders Angular applications on the server. It wires your app-shell component content into the `index.html`.
The content is put in the `index.html`, that is the goal, to display fast the first meaningful paint.

**You do not need the server folder any longer, no need to deploy it anywhere.**
(Assumed you do not use universal otherwise, which would not make sense with app-shell together anyways).
The browser folder can be deployed to CDN or anywhere else to be hosted.